# How to adjust monitor color balance with open source radeon drivers?

Tags: xorg, radeon, color-management

My display is too blueish, I would like to adjust its color balance.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting it with the xrandr command.

First find your device name by entering:

```
xrandr
```

There's an output line like:

```
LVDS connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x-axis y-axis) 367 mm x 230 mm
```

Then enter a command like (substituting for your device LVDS):

```
xrandr --output LVDS --verbose --gamma 1.0:1.0:1.5
```

Experiment with value, particularly the last, blue, value, until you like the results. The number must be floating-point, and they stand for **red**:**green**:**blue**.

The driver shouldn't matter.

See this man page.